# Digital Ocean managed Kubernetes volume in pending state

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, digital-ocean, volumes

It's not so digital ocean specific, would be really nice to verify if this is an expected behavior or not.

I'm trying to setup ElasticSearch cluster on DO managed Kubernetes cluster with helm chart from ElasticSearch [itself](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch)

And they say that I need to specify a `storageClassName` in a `volumeClaimTemplate` in order to use volume which is provided by managed kubernetes service. For DO it's `do-block-storages` according to their [docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/how-to/add-volumes/). Also seems to be it's not necessary to define PVC, helm chart should do it itself.

Here's config I'm using

```
# Specify node pool
nodeSelector:
    doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool: elasticsearch

# Shrink default JVM heap.
esJavaOpts: "-Xmx128m -Xms128m"

# Allocate smaller chunks of memory per pod.
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "512M"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "512M"

# Specify Digital Ocean storage
# Request smaller persistent volumes.
volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
extraInitContainers: |
  - name: create
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['mkdir', '/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/']
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      name: elasticsearch-master
  - name: file-permissions
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['chown', '-R', '1000:1000', '/usr/share/elasticsearch/']
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      name: elasticsearch-master
```

Helm chart i'm setting with terraform, but it doesn't matter anyway, which way you'll do it:

```
resource "helm_release" "elasticsearch" {
  name      = "elasticsearch"
  chart     = "elastic/elasticsearch"
  namespace = "elasticsearch"

  values = [
    file("charts/elasticsearch.yaml")
  ]
}
```

Here's what I've got when checking pod logs:

```
51s         Normal    Provisioning           persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-2   External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "elasticsearch/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-2"
2m28s       Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-2   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "dobs.csi.digitalocean.com" or manually created by system administrator
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is a volume. it should've been automagically provided by kubernetes. Describing persistent storage gives this:

```
holms@debian ~/D/c/s/b/t/s/post-infra> kubectl describe pvc elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0 --namespace elasticsearch
Name:          elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0
Namespace:     elasticsearch
StorageClass:  do-block-storage
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        app=elasticsearch-master
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: dobs.csi.digitalocean.com
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    elasticsearch-master-0
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                    From                                                                              Message
  ----    ------                ----                   ----                                                                              -------
  Normal  Provisioning          4m57s (x176 over 14h)  dobs.csi.digitalocean.com_master-setupad-eu_04e43747-fafb-11e9-b7dd-e6fd8fbff586  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "elasticsearch/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0"
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning  93s (x441 over 111m)   persistentvolume-controller                                                       waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "dobs.csi.digitalocean.com" or manually created by system administrator
```

I've google everything already, it seems to be everything is correct, and volume should be up withing DO side with no problems, but it hangs in pending state. Is this expected behavior or should I ask DO support to check what's going on their side?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What a strange situation, after I've changed `10Gi` to `10G` it started to work. Maybe it has to do something with a storage class it's self, but it started to work.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is expected behavior. This chart might not be compatible with Digital Ocean Kubernetes service.

[Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/overview/#known-issues) documentation has the following information in Known Issues section:

> - Support for resizing DigitalOcean Block Storage Volumes in Kubernetes has not yet been implemented.
> - In the DigitalOcean Control Panel, cluster resources (worker nodes, load balancers, and block storage volumes) are listed outside of the Kubernetes page. If you rename or otherwise modify these resources in the control panel, you may render them unusable to the cluster or cause the reconciler to provision replacement resources. To avoid this, manage your cluster resources exclusively with  `kubectl`  or from the control panel’s Kubernetes page.

In the [charts/stable/elasticsearch](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch#prerequisites-details) there are specific requirements mentioned:

> #### Prerequisites Details
>
> - Kubernetes 1.10+
> - PV dynamic provisioning support on the underlying infrastructure

You can ask Digital Ocean support for help or try to deploy ElasticSearch without helm chart.

It is even mentioned on [github](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch#usage-notes-and-getting-started) that:

> Automated testing of this chart is currently only run against GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine).

---

**Update:**

The same issue is present on my kubeadm ha cluster.

However I managed to get it working by manually creating `PersistentVolumes`'s for my `storageclass`.

My storageclass definition: `storageclass.yaml`:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ssd
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
```

```
$ kubectl apply -f storageclass.yaml
```

```
$ kubectl get sc
NAME   PROVISIONER   AGE
ssd    local         50m
```

My PersistentVolume definition: `pv.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: ssd
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - <name of the node>
```

```
kubectl apply -f pv.yaml
```

After that I ran helm chart:

```
helm install stable/elasticsearch --name my-release --set data.persistence.storageClass=ssd,data.storage=30Gi --set data.persistence.storageClass=ssd,master.storage=30Gi
```

PVC finally got bound.

```
$ kubectl get pvc -A
NAMESPACE   NAME                                     STATUS    VOLUME            CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
default     data-my-release-elasticsearch-data-0     Bound     task-pv-volume2   30Gi       RWO            ssd            17m
default     data-my-release-elasticsearch-master-0   Pending                                                              17m
```

Note that I only manually satisfied only single pvc and ElasticSearch manual volume provisioning might be very inefficient.

I suggest contacting DO support for automated volume provisioning solution.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/how-to/add-volumes/ but seems to be it possible to claim PVC..? I though helm chart does the same no?

Comment: :D I've just answered what's worked to me. As you can see it's just should've been `10G` instead of `10Gi`. IDK why this works, but it works, and I can reproduce this bug in DO k8s

Answer (score 0):

Use `do-block-storage-xfs` and remember that it has minimum memory limit requirement of 2GB